# How to distinguish the code from different library in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

For example, I use two library(A and B) in my project.There is a custom button class in library A, and the same to B.
How can system know which library the button is from?

Answer (score 0):

The libraries contain a list of the classes that they contain. You can read this list yourself by using the command-line tool `otool`. The `-o` switch lets you see the Objective-C section of the library:

> The  otool  command displays specified parts of object files or libraries.
>   ...
>   -o     Display the contents of the __OBJC segment used by the Objective-C run-time system.

So if you type `otool -o /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit`, you'll get output like this:

```
Contents of (__DATA,__objc_classlist) section
000000010001cf80 0x100021c50
           isa 0x100021c78
    superclass 0x0
         cache 0x0
        vtable 0x0
          data 0x10001db80 (struct class_ro_t *)
                    flags 0x10
            instanceStart 104
             instanceSize 288
                 reserved 0x0
               ivarLayout 0x0
                     name 0x10001954f Document
              baseMethods 0x10001d030 (struct method_list_t *)
                   entsize 24
                     count 78
                      name 0x10001591d makeWindowControllers
                     types 0x10001979b v16@0:8
                       imp 
                      name 0x100015fee writableTypesForSaveOperation:ignoreTemporaryState:
                     types 0x10001987f @28@0:8Q16c24
                       imp
```

...

When a process asks the OS to open a shared library or plug-in bundle, the OS will read the above data and generate a list of classes that the library contains. It also finds exported functions. You can read about the dynamic linker and loader (dyld). The function [`dlopen()`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dlopen.3.html) in particular is where this information is read from disk.

Also, your custom button classes in library A and B better be named differently. If they're not, then which one gets used at runtime is undefined. Either could get used. This is due to the fact that Objective-C does not have namespaces, so it looks things up by name at runtime.

Comment: I still do not know what data can be used to distinguish between different libraries.

Comment: I've added some additional information about dynamically loading classes at runtime.